# How can I access root directory in HTML? (Using / is not working)

Tags: html, filepath

So I'm trying to access my root directory in HTML but when I use / it is not working. So for example I'm trying to get my navigation css by doing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/nav.css">
```

The weird thing is, it works perfectly fine when I am using VS Code with the live server extension, but I just recently noticed when I run the index.html file alone none of the links starting with the / work. I know this is the issue too, because when I take away the / in the above line, it works perfectly fine again (only for the homepage page in the root directory already).

Comment: "it's not working" means nothing. Check in the browser dev tools what the error is, in the network tab, if the file is loaded or it gives some errors, for example 404

Comment: btw `/` means the root of the domain, if the file is in `https://example.com/directory/index.html`, it will try to load `https://example.com/nav.css`

Answer (score 1):

As Quentin points out, if you're loading the `index.html` file locally without a server, the root directory will be the root of your file system. If your requirement is for the `index.html` file to work locally on your professor's machine without a web server, you should use [relative paths](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp).

In order to traverse back up your file system from the current file, you can use paths that start with `../`

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated then the reason it's not working is because by loading the file directly you are now loading it as a local file rather than a file on website, and thus your URL base (Your `/`) is now referring to the root of your local file system. Which would likely be `C:\` on a windows system or your actual root `/` on a *nix system.

To actually solve your issue I would suggest one of the following solutions:

1. Just always run the project over HTTP through a server.
2. Go through your project and change all of your paths to be relative paths. You might be able to use a find replace in your editor to do this.
3. Use a [`<base>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag to specify what the base href of your web page should be.

If you can't use a server and just have a single HTML file then it might be quickest to use fix 3. You can probably get away with using `<base href=".">` to make the base the current directory of your index.html file which, I suspect, will be a drop in solution to make things work as they did before.

In future best consider this and how you are going to run the file, and what your URLs are going to be relative to. It's a wrinkle that can be easily missed nowadays that the tools we use in development are so good at hiding the details of how websites are actually deployed.

Answer (score 0):

> when I run the index.html file alone none of the links starting with the / work

If you are running `index.html` *alone* then the links starting with `/` will be relative to the root of your **file system**.

The browser doesn't (and can't) know which directory represents the root of your web site project.

Use a web server. Load the data over HTTP.

Comment: I unfortunately can't do this because I am making a website for a school project and my professor will run the index.html file, I don't think I will have a way of changing the way he runs it.

Comment: Then don't use URLs starting with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
./nav.css
```

It (I mean, `./`) loads files in the same directory of `index.html`, same as `nav.css`. With VS Code, I bet `./nav.css` should work for the live preview too: using an external HTTP server (such as `http-server` on Node.js) helps, because it takes the current directory (where `index.html` is) as the root and you can easily reach `/nav.css`. Without a live server, the relative path could be reached as I said with `./nav.css` (a typical *NIX path) or simply `nav.css` without slashes on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<base>` is a good idea.
It will change the base href in the whole page, which might cause problems when using other links or section navigation.